# How to use email checker in dwm status bar

Tags: email, dwm

I have the following .xsession file

```
#!/bin/sh

xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr

while xsetroot -name "`date`"
do
      sleep 1
done &

feh --bg-scale wallpaper.jpg &
/home/aamalyshev/bin/dwm
```

What program can I use to add an email checker near the `date` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these instructions: (you will need `fetchmail`)

http://dwm.suckless.org/scripts/email_notifier_script

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer something like `mutt` instead of `fetchmail`. Do you know something about this solution?

Answer (score 1):

I use mutt with offlineimap so this might not apply to you but for the offlineimap case you just have to check the files in `$MAILDIR/account/INBOX/new`, e.g.

```
maildirs="$HOME/.mail/*/INBOX/new/"
numofnewmail="$(find $maildirs -type f | wc -l)"
xsetroot -name "mail: $numofnewmail, $date"
```

where `$MAILDIR` is usually `~/.mail`. Also, depend on your mail account and your configuration also the name of the inbox folder can vary (e.g. `Inbox` instead of `INBOX`).

Also, you didn't ask for it, but here's [a wizard that can help you setup mutt with offlineimap](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/mutt-wizard).